# Error 148 Dimension different - The symbol is referenced with more/less

Tags: gams-math

I am not able to sort out the Error 148 in GAMS Studio 39.3 for my problem.

148  Dimension different - The symbol is referenced with more/less indices as declared

following is the details:

```
Sets
EV          'EV unit'/ev1*ev1/
Asev1       'set ev index for values of sch' /1*2/
taev        'set of arrival'/taev1*taev1/
tdev        'set of departure'/tdev1*tdev1/
t           ’time periods’ /t1*t2/
w           ’scenarios’ /w1*w2/;


SCALAR 
Pev          ’EV power traded in the Energy market’/7.8/;


PARAMETER    
Asev        'alphasch(ev) values of alphasch'
/1         0
2          1/;


PARAMETER 
weigth(w)           ’weight of scenarios’
/w1  0.05
w2   0.05/;


POSITIVE VARIABLES
As(ev,t,w)           'EV scheduling in time period t';


EQUATION
Pev1                 'power output of EV'


Pev1(t,w)..     Pev=e=sum(ev,Pev(ev,t,w)*Asev('ev,t,w'));
```

I am not sure where i am making mistake however i am getting Error 148.
Error 148  Dimension different - The symbol is referenced with more/less
****         indices as declared

Note: I got $148 error under w)*

Answer (score 0):

```
Pev1(t,w)..     Pev=e=sum(ev,Pev(ev,t,w)*Asev('ev,t,w'));
```

First, you probably don't want the quotes at the end, which makes `ev,t,w` one specific element. So, you should change it to this:

```
Pev1(t,w)..     Pev=e=sum(ev,Pev(ev,t,w)*Asev(ev,t,w));
```

But still, this does not work. You defined `Asev` as 1-dimensional parameter with the elements `1` and `2` above. That does not fit your usage here. So, what do you actually intend? Either the definition of `Asev` must be wrong or your usage. Or did you actually want to use `As` here instead, like this?

```
Pev1(t,w)..     Pev=e=sum(ev,Pev(ev,t,w)*As(ev,t,w));
```

This would resolve the problem for the last term, but give an error before, since also the use of `Pev` (with 3 indices here) does not match your definition as `Scalar` above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback!

As or Asev is just the declaration.

Firstly, I removed the quotes at the end, which makes (ev,t,w)

and here it is

Pev1(t,w)..     Pev=e=sum(ev,Pev(ev,t,w)*As(ev,t,w));

The problem for the last term is still existing.

I didn't get it you saying " the use of Pev (with 3 indices here) does not match your definition as Scalar above."

I think the Pev (with 3 indices here) match with the scalar above

Comment: "As or Asev is just the declaration" - Not sure, what you mean here. They are two different symbols, one is a variable, the other a parameter. - "I think the Pev (with 3 indices here) match with the scalar above" - No, it actually does not. Scalar means 0 indices, so you cannot access it with 3 indices. BTW: It would be better to write a reply like yours under the answer as comment instead of as new answer.

Comment: That would be better, but still has just two indices, not three, right?

Comment: I am not sure about the SCALAR and indices here, I have reviewed some other codes in GAMS and they do have more than 2 or three indices in the SCALAR. As I have already lot of other symbols, so according to my mentioned approach and problem, I use Pev for Power of electric vehicle. i also have table for EV data which contains Pev value defined as power of EV.

Comment: in my new code, I consider As only a "Parameter"

Comment: Scalar has zero dimensions by definition (see https://www.gams.com/41/docs/UG_DataEntry.html#UG_DataEntry_Scalars). Not sure about the status of your problem after the latest comment. If you still have a question after some code changes, it would probably be the best to update your initial question.

Comment: I will get back to you shortly after revising my problem